# Default Definer Rights in Method Definition

Tags: security, plsql, secure-coding, checkmarx

In Checkmarx report, I'm getting the below:

> Default Definer Rights in Method Definition.

It has highlighted a case statement(shown beow)

`case when v_risk='RISK' then 'Y' else 'N'`

Please let me know what the issue is and what needs to be done to resolve this?
Note: authid current_user is already added in the package.

Answer (score 0):

This finding can be solved by adding AUTHID CURRENT_USER clause in your procedure or function where your case statement is in

```
create or replace procedure sample_procedure
authid current_user
as
begin

...
case when v_risk='RISK' then 'Y' else 'N'
```

Comment: This is already added, but still I'm getting the error.

Comment: @Natty maybe share some more code so we can get more context?